# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Trying to show the length of the data that is received from api response.but it say cannot read property of undefined

```
async  componentDidMount() {
        Users.getAppAuthUser(1,true).then((res)=>{
            this.setState({data:res});
            this.setState({loading:false});
        })
        console.log(this.state.data);

}
render() {
    return (
         <div >                    
            <span >({  this.state.data ===[] ?    0 :  this.state.data.accounts.length })
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your first render is happening even before data is loading from promise. You can safeguard it by checking if `this.state.data` exists.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you can do is

```
<div>
{ this.state.data && <span> {{this.state.data.length}} </span> }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it could happen because while the rendering is processing, the state is not done yet so it won't get the whole properties of the keys inside the state. In this case it hasn't finished loading `data` so `length` is not available.

`async` before `componentDidMount` is not valid here.

```
state = {
  data: [], loading: false
}

componentDidMount() {
    Users.getAppAuthUser(1, true).then((res)=> ({
        this.setState({data: res, loading:false});
    }))
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>                    
            {this.state.data && <span>{this.state.data.accounts.length}</span>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

If this line doesn't work `{this.state.data && <span>{this.state.data.accounts.length}</span>}` do this instead:

`{this.state.data && this.state.data.accounts && <span>{this.state.data.accounts.length}</span>}`

If you using lodash you may import get:

```
import get from 'lodash.get';

...

<div>                    
  <span>{get(this.state, 'data.accounts.length', null)}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The reason to why u r getting undefined is not proper usage of async/await.**
[Read to get more info bro](https://medium.com/@theflyingmantis/async-await-react-promise-testing-a0d454b5461b)

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: json });
    }
```

**You should use it like this**